# Ubuntu 20.04 apt installed kaffeine won't record and snap kaffeine never runs

Tags: 20.04, tv

I have had kaffeine running really reliably for many years, but recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04, and kaffeine was still running.
I realised the other day that I cannot record any TV programmes now - which seems a recent issue - maybe around the time I got my bluray drive to work as a bluray drive!
I can watch TV, just not record anything - yet I rarely watch live TV, so this is an issue!
I also tried installing the snap version (kaffeine-player) which crashes on loading, so I have removed it.
I have for many years been frustrated that every time I load kaffeine, one has to update the storage locations and pre/post-record additional times, and I note this is now saved - so maybe this is an issue with the kaffeine update.

The following is what I see when I run the apt version of kaffeine from the command line:

```
    kaffeine %U
19-02-22 08:08:30.850 [Info    ] kaffeine.dvb: Using built-in dvb device manager
19-02-22 08:08:31.150 [Info    ] kaffeine.dev: Found dvb device P14f1880200709601: Conexant CX22702 DVB-T
19-02-22 08:08:31.186 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/stock/16/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.187 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/stock/22/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.187 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/stock/24/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.187 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/stock/32/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.187 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/stock/48/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.187 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/stock/64/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.187 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/stock/128/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.192 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "Legacy" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/8x8/legacy/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.192 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "Legacy" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/16x16/legacy/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.192 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "UI" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/16x16/ui/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.192 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "Legacy" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/22x22/legacy/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.192 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "Legacy" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/24x24/legacy/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.192 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "UI" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/24x24/ui/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.192 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "Legacy" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/32x32/legacy/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.192 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "UI" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/32x32/ui/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.192 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "Legacy" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/48x48/legacy/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.192 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "UI" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/48x48/ui/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.192 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "Legacy" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/64x64/legacy/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.192 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "UI" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/64x64/ui/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.192 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "Legacy" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/96x96/legacy/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.192 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "UI" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/96x96/ui/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.193 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "Legacy" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/256x256/legacy/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.193 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "Legacy" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/512x512/legacy/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.193 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "Legacy" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/legacy/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.193 [Warning ] Invalid Context= "UI" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/ui/"
19-02-22 08:08:31.349 [Warning ] kf5.kservice.services: KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType "ThumbCreator" not found
19-02-22 08:08:31.350 [Warning ] kf5.kservice.services: KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType "ThumbCreator" not found
19-02-22 08:08:31.665 [Warning ] kf5.kservice.services: KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType "ThumbCreator" not found
19-02-22 08:08:31.666 [Warning ] kf5.kservice.services: KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType "ThumbCreator" not found
libva info: VA-API version 1.13.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_13
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
mesa: for the --simplifycfg-sink-common option: may only occur zero or one times!
mesa: for the --global-isel-abort option: may only occur zero or one times!
mesa: for the --amdgpu-atomic-optimizations option: may only occur zero or one times!
[00007fafc0002cf0] glconv_vaapi_x11 gl error: vaDeriveImage: operation failed
[00007fafc4014d40] main video output error: video output creation failed
[00007fafcc031010] main decoder error: failed to create video output
[00007fafcc031010] avcodec decoder: Using G3DVL VDPAU Driver Shared Library version 1.0 for hardware decoding
[00007fafcc031010] avcodec decoder error: hardware acceleration picture allocation failed
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fafc4015780] get_buffer() failed
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fafc4015780] thread_get_buffer() failed
[mpeg2video @ 0x7fafc4015780] get_buffer() failed (-1 (nil))
```

Kaffeine is version "kaffeine 2.0.18"
The version of Ubuntu is "Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS""
and

```
uname -r
5.13.0-30-generic
```

Please let me know if any other information is required..
Many thanks for any help...

Comment: What did you do to make the blue ray drive work? That may be the problem. For me I installed the drive and did nothing with the software and the drive works well. Can play and burn disks with it.

Comment: I think Kaffeine was working after the bluray drive - and I installed e.g. the bluray libraries. If I knew how to revert to the previous iteration of kaffeine, I might try that - as that I can see is different.
Many thanks for your help! It is appreciated.